# Error 0x8007F303 occurs during printing of reports from MOSS using SRS viewer web part

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, reporting-services, moss

When attempting to print using the SSRS Viewer Web Part in SharePoint I get the following error.

> An error occured during printing. (0x8007F303)

The settings we are using in this box (production) are exactly the same as the settings in testing where this works perfectly fine.

Anyone have any good ideas or faced this before?

Answer (score 1):

I found some ideas by Googling.

- [Someone had issue with "SSRS server configured for Sharepoint Integrated mode with Cumulative update package 3 for SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 2" but "the problem vanished after installing the .NET framework 3.0 SP1"](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=307315)
- You can get this error if you have ["old instances of the old 
  ReportViewer control in your web sites bin directories or anywhere else it 
  could be accessed by your web application."](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.sqlserver.reportingsvcs&tid=570c2859-0e7a-4d6d-87de-ea8576963565&p=1)
- It's another error 0x800C0005, but there is [an incident where the error only occurred in production environment](https://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=1012031&SiteID=1). bradsy@Microsoft says

> You can enable Client print logging by
>   setting the follow reg key. Once
>   enabled, you can look in your print
>   users temporary (cd %temp%) directory
>   and find a print log file. Windows
>
> Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Reporting Services]`
>   `"LogRSClientPrintInfo"=dword:00000001`
>
> You can send the log file to me and I
>   can take a look to see if there is any
>   extra information.

Maybe you should collect the log and send it to the forum.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a custom authentication in use for Reporting Services defined in your
web.config. Check if that is the case, remove the custom authentication and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem obvious, but have you checked that you have at least one valid printer installed and available?